# Closed-form of $\tan(\frac{\pi }{9})$.

Tags: geometry

How can I get the closed-form of the above expression.I tried to find it but I can't do.

Comment: [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=tan%28π%2F9%29) cannot find a closed form.

Comment: @lhf: A case of praising with faint damnation?  I'm sure WA could find it if the question were posed in just the right way.

Comment: See [casus irreducibilis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casus_irreducibilis).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $x=\tan(\pi/9)$.

First,
$$\tan 3a=\frac{\tan a+\tan 2a}{1-\tan a\tan 2a}=\frac{\tan a+\frac{2\tan a}{1-\tan^2 a}}{1-\frac{2\tan^2 a}{1-\tan^2a}}=\frac{3\tan a-\tan^3a}{1-3\tan^2a}$$

Since $\tan(\pi/3)=\sqrt 3$ you have

$$\sqrt 3=\frac{3x-x^3}{1-3x^2}$$

Therefore, $\tan(\pi/9)$ is one of the roots of the equation
$$X^3-3\sqrt 3X^2-3X+\sqrt 3=0$$

If you are able to solve it, you will eventually get that 'closed form'. Cubic equations have a [method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Cardano.27s_method) to solve them, but it is far from simple. Alternatively you may use a computer program to solve the equation, like Maxima, Mathematica, Maple, etc.

Comment: The closed form of that root is $$x = \sqrt{3}+\frac{1-i \sqrt{3}}{\sqrt[3]{½\left(-\sqrt{3}+i\right)}}+\sqrt[3]{½ \left(-\sqrt{3}+i\right)} \cdot \left(1+i \sqrt{3}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

Do you allow complex radicals in your "closed form"?  (If you apply Cardano's formulas in ajotatxe's solution you will get them.)  If so, why not just use radicals like
$$
(-1)^{1/9}
$$
so that you can write
$$
\tan\frac{\pi}{9} = \frac{-2 \left( -1 \right) ^{5/9}+4 \left( -1
 \right) ^{4/9}-2 \left( -1 \right) ^{2/9}-2
(-1)^{1/9}}{\sqrt{3}}+\sqrt {3}
$$
??

Comment: WA does suggest that.